# Spring MVC update without redundant code?

Tags: spring-mvc, crud, spring-form

I'm working on a Spring MVC controller and views to implement CRUD operations for a simple object named Partner. The update operation troubles me. It seems like I need to write several lines of code manually that I expected Spring MVC would take care of automatically. Is there a best practice that I'm missing here?

Here's my view:

```
<%@ include file="include.jsp"%>

<form:form commandName="partner">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id:</td>
            <td><form:input path="id" disabled="true" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Logo:</td>
            <td><form:input path="logo" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>On-screen text:</td>
            <td><form:textarea path="onScreenText" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save Changes" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
```

And here's my controller method for the update operation:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/partner/{partnerId}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public ModelAndView updatePartner(@ModelAttribute Partner partner, @PathVariable int partnerId) {
    EntityManager entityManager = DatabaseHelper.getEntityManager();
    try {
        Partner partnerToUpdate = entityManager.find(Partner.class, partnerId);
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        partnerToUpdate.setId(partnerId);
        partnerToUpdate.setName(partner.getName());
        partnerToUpdate.setLogo(partner.getLogo());
        partnerToUpdate.setOnScreenText(partner.getOnScreenText());
        entityManager.persist(partnerToUpdate);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/partner");
}
```

The lines of code that trouble me are:

```
Partner partnerToUpdate = entityManager.find(Partner.class, partnerId);
partnerToUpdate.setId(partnerId);
partnerToUpdate.setName(partner.getName());
partnerToUpdate.setLogo(partner.getLogo());
partnerToUpdate.setOnScreenText(partner.getOnScreenText());
```

Do I really need to look up the existing Partner in the database and explicitly update each field of that object? I already have a Partner object with all the right values. Is there no way to store that object directly to the database?

I've already looked at [Spring MVC CRUD controller best pactice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928482/spring-mvc-crud-controller-best-pactice), but that didn't quite answer my question.

Comment: You can try using `partner.setId(partnerToUpdate.getId()); entityManager.merge(partner);` but It only works if `partner` is a complete entity.

Comment: @AVolpe, your suggestion to use merge worked.

Comment: I will add an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29) to update the desired values, something like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/partner/{partnerId}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ModelAndView updatePartner(@ModelAttribute Partner partner, @PathVariable int partnerId) {
        EntityManager entityManager = DatabaseHelper.getEntityManager();
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            partner.setId(partnerId);
            entityManager.merge(partner);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/partner");
    }
```

Also, I recommend You to use the [DAO Pattern](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object) and Spring Transaction Support with `@Transactional` and `@Repository`

Answer (score 1):

As one possible suggestion, you could lookup the existing `Partner` object as part of model creation so that this model instance backs the form and Spring binds the fields directly to it. One way to achieve this would be to create an explicit method in the controller responsible for creating the model.

For example:

```
@ModelAttribute("partner")
public Partner createModel(@PathVariable int partnerId) {
    Partner partner = entityManager.find(Partner.class, partnerId);
    return partner;
}
```

And then you could remove the copying from the `updatePartner` method - because Spring will already have bound the form fields directly to the loaded `Partner` object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/partner/{partnerId}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public ModelAndView updatePartner(@ModelAttribute("partner") Partner partner) {
    EntityManager entityManager = DatabaseHelper.getEntityManager();
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(partner);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/partner");
}
```

One caveat - because the `createModel` method would get called for every request to the controller (not just `updatePartner`), the `partnerId` path variable would need to be present in all requests.

There's a post [here](http://tedyoung.me/2011/05/09/spring-mvc-optional-path-variables/) which goes over a solution to that issue.

Comment: You should really have a service/repository to hide the usage of the `EntityManager` the controller is not the place to start/stop a transaction. And you probably want to use springs declarative tx management so you don't have to take care of that yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum - agreed. I lifted the code from the OP to illustrate my answer. Separating the persistence detail from the controller and hiding the EntityManager would certainly be wise.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to follow AVolpe's suggestion and didn't need to create a separate method annotated with ModelAttribute. I'll follow the recommendation by M. Deinum and @Will Keeling to create a separate service/repository.